# Azure ikev2 with meraki

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-vpn, vnet

I am trying to setup a S2S VPN to our Meraki MX84 Firewall

The Meraki supports only policy based IKEv1 vpn.

Is there anybody that has a working VPN with a Meraki MX unit?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Meraki MX Devices work with Azure Virtual Network Gateways - BUT, only with Policy Based IKEv1.

Be sure to choose 'Policy-Based' under Gateway type, when creating the VNG.

[image: azure snip]

Answer (score 0):

Please note as of 6/6/2018, Meraki devices are not compatible.  See this list for more details.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-about-vpn-devices

Answer (score 0):

Meraki does not support IKEv2 and therefore route based gateway won't work. Meraki supports only IKEv1, used by the policy based GW. There's long feature request discussion chain on the Meraki site regarding this topic [1].

The alternatives seem to be:

- Switch to policy based gateway
- Deploy Meraki vMX100 virtual appliance (comes with license cost) [2]
- Terminate the VPN connection for example on Ubuntu/strongSwan equipped VM [3]

[1] https://community.meraki.com/t5/Security-SD-WAN/Feature-Request-IKEv2-Support-in-MX-appliances/td-p/2860/page/2

[2] https://documentation.meraki.com/MX/Installation_Guides/vMX100_Setup_Guide_for_Microsoft_Azure

[3] http://www.ifm.net.nz/cookbooks/meraki-vpn-to-azure.html

Answer (score 0):

Meraki Code 15.x does have IKEv2 - it's currently in BETA and requires Meraki Support to enable.